# Creating a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 that pulls between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I'm a complete novice to SQL Server. I'm trying to create a stored procedure where you can search between two dates. I'd like my EXEC to read something like

```
EXEC Procedure TimeSheetIndexSearch (Date, Date)
```

(In which case, you'd input the dates before running EXEC.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TimesheetIndexSearch
AS
   SELECT 
       Timesheets.Hours AS Hours, 
       Timesheets.DateWorked AS DateWorked, 
       Timesheets.Description AS Description,
       Timesheets.Id AS Id, 
       Users.Name AS UserName, 
       Projects.Name AS ProjectName
   FROM   
       Timesheets
   INNER JOIN 
       Users ON Timesheets.UserId = Users.Id
   INNER JOIN 
       Projects ON Timesheets.ProjectId = Projects.Id;
```

There's only one date column (no begindate or enddate). Do I use `Where`? Or `Order By`?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. The challenge here is we don't know what you want this to do. Do you to have this return rows where DateWorked is between the two date values? Regardless of the query itself the way you do this is with parameters. A quick google search will provide hundreds of thousands of examples of stored procedures with parameters. The thing you need to decide is if you are using mysql or sqlserver, they are NOT the same thing.

Comment: `...WHERE DateWorked BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate`

Comment: Especially for somebody new I would use caution with BETWEEN. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the help. I was doing a ton of google searches, but they weren't adding up. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Not sure why somebody downvoted this question. It is clear that the OP is very new to this and did their best explaining what they wanted. Some people get on downvote binges for things sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TimesheetIndexSearch (@Start DATETIME, @End DATETIME)
AS
SELECT Timesheets.Hours AS Hours
       , Timesheets.DateWorked AS DateWorked
       , Timesheets.Description AS Description
       , Timesheets.Id AS Id
       , Users.Name AS UserName
       , Projects.Name AS ProjectName
FROM   Timesheets
       INNER JOIN Users ON Timesheets.UserId = Users.Id
       INNER JOIN Projects ON Timesheets.ProjectId = Projects.Id
WHERE  Timesheets.DateWorked >= @Start
       AND Timesheets.DateWorked <= @End;
```

You can also use the keyword `between` as follows:

```
WHERE Timesheets.DateWorked BETWEEN @Start AND @End
```

Just be careful with `between`, as it is inclusive of the dates in the variables, the first approach is cleaner, and easier to read by all.

To run the proc you'd use

```
EXEC TimesheetIndexSearch '2015-01-01','2015-01-10'
```

Comment: Looks like I was on the right track! Thanks for your help. Pretty straightforward, really.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create a stored procedure for this.  Create a stored function.  This is much more versatile because you can use it in the `from` clause of a `select`:

```
CREATE FRUN TimesheetIndexSearch (
    @Start date,
    @End date
)
RETURNS table
AS
    RETURN (SELECT ts.Hours AS Hours, ts.DateWorked AS DateWorked,              
                   ts.Description AS Description,
                   ts.Id AS Id, u.Name AS UserName, p.Name AS ProjectName
            FROM Timesheets ts INNER JOIN
                 Users u
                 ON ts.UserId = u.Id INNER JOIN
                 Projects p
                 ON ts.ProjectId = p.Id
            WHERE ts.DateWorked >= @Start AND ts.DateWorked <= @End
           );
```

You can then use this as:

```
select f.*
from dbo.frun('2015-01-01', '2015-02-01');
```

Also, note how the use of table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.